# How do I include external graphics in my knitr documents?

Tags: r, graphics, knitr, r-markdown

I have been using knitr in conjunction with my `R` work.

I have some external graphics that I would like to include in my knitr HTML document.

I can't seem to find a method to do so.  Should I use R Markdown or is there a more knitr-specific manner to do this?

Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: markdown image syntax works. `![Alt text](/path/to/img.jpg)`. http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#img

Comment: This is also in the markdown quick reference in knitr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the notation

```
!['Gauss'](https://goo.gl/eXN77h)
```

as in this [OpenCPU example app](https://demo.ocpu.io/markdownapp/www/).